# Why won’t this form using react-hook-form reset back to defaultValues?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I’m using react-hook-form in a simple form with a Reset and Submit button. When using the `reset()` method provided by react-hook-form, it always clears the form completely instead of resetting it back to the `defaultValues`.

Here is my component with everything but relative code stripped out:

```
const FormBasicInfo = ({
    defaultValues,
    onSubmit,
}) => {
    const formMethods = useForm({ defaultValues });
    const { formState: { errors, isDirty, isSubmitting }, reset } = formMethods;

    const fields = useMemo(() => [
        [
            {
                label: 'First Name',
                name: 'firstName',
                required: true,
                type: 'text',
            },
            {
                label: 'Last Name',
                name: 'lastName',
                required: true,
                type: 'text',
            },
        ],
        {
            label: 'Email Address',
            name: 'email',
            required: true,
            type: 'email',
        },
        {
            label: 'Mobile',
            name: 'phone',
            type: 'tel',
        },
        {
            label: 'Job Position',
            name: 'position',
            type: 'text',
        },
    ], []);

    const handleReset = () => {
        // reset(defaultValues); // ← Clears the form completely
        reset({ firstName: 'Brandon' }); // ← Clears the form completely
    };

    return (
        <FormProvider { ...formMethods }>
            <form noValidate onSubmit={ formMethods.handleSubmit(onSubmit) }>
                {
                    fields.map(field => {
                        const isArray = Array.isArray(field);
                        if (isArray) {
                            return (
                                <SplitFields key={ `split-${field[0]?.name}` }>
                                    { field.map(splitField => (
                                        <SplitInput
                                            disabled={ isSubmitting }
                                            error={ errors?.[splitField?.name]?.message }
                                            key={ splitField?.name }
                                            { ...splitField }
                                        />
                                    )) }
                                </SplitFields>
                            );
                        }
                        return (
                            <Input
                                disabled={ isSubmitting }
                                error={ errors?.[field?.name]?.message }
                                key={ field?.name }
                                { ...field }
                            />
                        );
                    })
                }
                {
                    isDirty ? (
                        <FormCTA>
                            {
                                !isSubmitting ? (
                                    <Button
                                        label="Cancel"
                                        onClick={ handleReset }
                                        variant="light"
                                    />
                                ) : null
                            }
                            <Button
                                disabled={ isSubmitting }
                                label="Update"
                                loading={ isSubmitting }
                                type="submit"
                                variant="primary-2"
                            />
                        </FormCTA>
                    ) : null
                }
            </form>
        </FormProvider>
    );
};
```

What am I missing here? I need to allow the user to hit “Cancel” and return the form back to its original state with `defaultValues` loaded.

Comment: Is SplitInput and Input [registered](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) field?

Comment: It sure is. It’s just a styled-component wrapping an input.

Comment: And does "Clears the form completely" mean that it clears input's value or all inputs just disappear?

Comment: The inputs are completely empty after reset instead of defaulting back to their defaultValues.

Comment: Can you try putting this in a codesandbox without the custom components?  The only major oddity I can see here is the fact that <Button/>'s by themselves actually submit inside forms unless you say type="button" since submit is the default (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement).  That said there may be more to this story. (like why aren't your components registering with the fields?). Therefore working off a codesandbox would help get to a better answer.